# Restore of MSDB fails with different version error but the versions are the same

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, msdb

Trying to restore MSDB to a replacement server and getting this message:

> Msg 3168, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> The backup of the system database on the device e:\sqlbackup\2024-02-27_msdb_DEV.bak cannot be restored because it was created by a different version of the server (**15.00.4335**) than this server (**15.00.4355**).
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The versions are different: 4**33**5 versus 4**35**5

4335 -> SQL 2019 CU 23

4355 -> SLQ 2019 CU 25

You could either patch the lower versioned server or uninstall the CU on the higher versioned server, then patch it to the specific version.